# Radial gradient background

Tags: html, css

I want to make a decent but professional looking attractive body background for my website.
It should look like Twitter's background:

[image: Twitter gradient background]

Can you see the blue shaded background? That's exactly what I want to make.
I don't have a good experience in web development and I'm pretty new to it. Please help me to create this background.

Comment: Did you take a look at the CSS with a page inspector?

Comment: No. I am pretty new to Web development. Can you please guide me through it?

Comment: Take a look at this links
http://www.css3maker.com/css-gradient.html
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this generator [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html)

Example markup using those colors:

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #A3CEF2 0%, #5D95CC 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #A3CEF2 0%, #5D95CC 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #A3CEF2 0%, #5D95CC 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 506, color-stop(0, #A3CEF2), color-stop(1, #5D95CC));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle farthest-corner, #A3CEF2 0%, #5D95CC 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #A3CEF2 0%, #5D95CC 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

The css they use are as follows:

```
.mobile-callout {
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #94D2F8, #3A92C8) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
.front-page {
 background-color: #292929;
}
```

So I guess the code you are looking for is:

```
'...': radial-gradient(circle, #94D2F8, #3A92C8) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

Comment: what should be in place of `'...'`

Comment: Your element from html.